# Why does Stack Overflow looks abnormal sometimes?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, firefox

Sometimes Stack Overflow/meta looks a little bit different than usual; really horrible in fact. See the screenshots below.

[this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pP6BPqZSaLU&feature=youtu.be) shows my problem when i view meta.

I'm using Mozilla Firefox 32.0.2,why does this happen? This problem occurs only sometimes.

It shows all questions and  answers as down voted by me, even when it's not allowed to down vote your own answers.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice, today there are only downvotes... Still, only upvotes would be interesting too.

Comment: @Deduplicator what do you mean ?

Comment: What operating system are you using? I can't repro using Firefox 32.03 on Windows 8.1. Do you have any plugins/add-ons? If so, try disabling and look again. Are the dev tools telling you anything about bad JS or any assets that are not loading (CSS/JS)?

Comment: @Deduplicator: that is the point; the vote button *display* has been mucked up. The OP didn't actually downvote anything.

Comment: @Oded yes windows 8.1 and firefox 32.0.3 .i have installed at least 3 addons but i restarted firefox with addon disabled(there is a option to do that in firefox) but problem not solved now stackoverflow looks perfectly but now same happens on meta.but all other pages looks perfect

Comment: something screwing up the sprite-map positions?

Comment: down voters know how to fix it...

Comment: It looks like you are zoomed. Press `Ctrl+0` to reset your zoom.

Comment: @vcsjones i just try it.but nothing happens .but much  thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @Lankymart has clearly defined *what* is happening -- incorrect [CSS sprite](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=3c6263c3453b) position -- note also that many of the upvote buttons are displaying as down arrows, but that doesn't explain *why*.  I can't reproduce on FF32.0 on Windows 7, at any zoom.

Comment: @AmeliaBR It could be a combination of that and the something blocking the javascript from doing it's magic.

Comment: @AmeliaBR actually downside m  is half of favorite mark.my screen resolution is 1900*900 .but i don't know why because it happens only sometimes .now it happen to meta too.

Comment: this video shows the problem but it shows meta site.but problem is same https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pP6BPqZSaLU&feature=youtu.be

Comment: It looks like an elaborate unicorn prank.  Wait until April.  Or ask your team members to wait until then :)

Comment: @HansPassant why?what happen in April ?